# RAID level 0 benifits

Tags: hard-drive, raid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RAID 0 performance gains?](https://superuser.com/questions/11640/raid-0-performance-gains)

What exactly is the (hypothetical) performance gain with RAID level 0? Does it essentially double all the specs of the single hard drive or is does it work differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doubles the sequential read and write speeds. Latency for small reads or writes is generally unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically it would double speeds but in practice it generally falls somewhere short of that. As with other similar RAID levels, RAID0 benefits from the multiple-spindle effect where reads/write speeds are increased purely based on the fact that the additional spindles give additional simultaneous sector access.